# Gradle couldn't parse a file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just installed Android Studio and the whole SDK.
Unfortunately, if I create a project for both Android and Android Wear, gradle fails instantly saying

> "Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.0.1"

and just after that

> "Could not parse POM %path-to-my-sdk%\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-analytics-impl\10.0.1\play-services-analytics-impl-10.0.1.pom".

I checked that file and it is empty (as multiple other .pom files are. I re-downloaded that part of the SDK even though it is already up-to-date but it still doesn't work.

Any way to fix that ?

Comment: Did you specify SDK and JRE/JDK paths? JAVA_HOME, and so on?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct on this side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a platform, platform and build tools via SDK manager. Those dependencies are in the bottom.